# Induced linear operator on the dual space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a general question. Suppose you have a bounded linear operator $T: (L^p)^* \to (L^{q})^*$. Is there always a bounded linear operator $T': L^q \to L^p$ naturally induced by $T$? If no, are there some additional conditions that make it true? If yes, do we have $\|T\| = \|T'\|?$ I know that the converse to this question is true, but I am not sure for this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $1<p<\infty$, $L^p$ is reflexive (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space)).

Thus there is a naturally induced bounded linear operator 
$$T':((L^q)^*)^*=L^q\longrightarrow  ((L^p)^*)^*=L^p.$$

It is simply the transpose (modulo the identification of the biduals with the spaces).

And between normed spaces, the norm of the transpose is the norm of the original operator.

I am not sure about other values of $p$, though.

Comment: Thanks! This is a really important fact!